# What is this snake

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

I took a picture of this snake in Switzerland (Geneva Area):

[image: Snake]

It looks to be an adder but cannot be sure about which species.

In Switzerland we have two kinds of adder:

1. [*Vipera berus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_berus)
2. [*Vipera aspis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipera_aspis)

For me it looks like a *Vipera berus*, but all the images I saw from both species (and the variations) I cannot be sure.

Comment: amazing that you stood long enough to take a picture of an unknown snake.. I would be running my lungs out..

Comment: I was at reasonable distance and with a 70-200mm it helps. But yes I recognised an adder (lightly venomous) but I know they are quiet as long you don't go next to them.

Comment: An generally speaking, snakes in Europe tends to escape before attacking

Comment: I'm not an expert so don't feel qualified to answer, but a bit of reading suggests to me that it is Vipera aspis because the head looks rather broad and there is no clear dorsal zigzag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's an *Vipera Aspis*.

from wikipedia:

> The dorsal markings vary strongly, but only rarely take the form of a
>   clear zigzag, as in V. berus.

[image]

Your Snake in Maximum RGB Color (Broken ZigZag)

[image]

*Vipera Aspis* from Google Image

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After searching about the repartition of both snakes around Geneva, I found these maps that confirm [`vipera berus`](http://www2.unine.ch/repository/default/content/sites/karch/files/Bilder/Cartes_r%C3%A9partitions/Carte%20de%20r%C3%A9partition_Vip%C3%A8re%20p%C3%A9liade.jpg) is not present in Geneva area as [`vipera aspis`](http://www2.unine.ch/repository/default/content/sites/karch/files/Bilder/Cartes_r%C3%A9partitions/Carte%20de%20r%C3%A9partition_Vip%C3%A8re%20aspic.jpg) is